# Express + Passport, Error: can't post request to passport and not throw any error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

trying first time node with passport for signing to app and can't get any error in command.

after too much load it responds:

> No data received
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

can't find any solution for this error.

routes

```
loginRouter.route('/login')
        .get(loginController.getLogin)
        .post(loginController.postLogin);
```

postlogin function :

```
var postLogin = function(req, res, next){
        passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/',
            failureRedirect: '/auth/login',
            failureFlash : true
        });
    };
```

passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var User = require('../app/models/model')().User;

module.exports = function(){

    passport.use('local',new localStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function (username, password, done){
        User.findOne({
            where: {
                username: username
            }
        }).then(function(user){
            if(!user) {
                console.log(user);
                done(null, false, req.flash('invalid credentials try again'));
            } else if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
                done(null, false, req.flash('invalid credentials try again'));
            } else {
                done(null, user);
            }
        });
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function (user,done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done){
        User.findOne({where: {id: id}}).then(function(user){
            done(null, user);
        });
    });
};
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    flash = require('express-flash'),
    app = express(),
    port = 80;


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true } ));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'lirary',
    cookie: {
        maxage: 1200000
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

require('./config/passport')();
app.set('views','./resources/views');
app.set('view engine','ejs');

require(__dirname + '/app/routes/routes')(app);

app.listen(port,function(err){
    console.log('server running on : '+ port)
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just little change in my route and solved this now.

```
loginRouter.post('/login',
        function (req, res, next) {
            console.log(User.validate());
            next();
        },
        passport.authenticate('local',{     
                successRedirect: '/dashboard',
                failureRedirect: '/auth/login',
                failureFlash : true
            }
        ));
```